# Alert do Bootstrap desaparecer

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".alertaLogin").fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 3000 ).fadeOut( 400 );
});
</script>
```

O objetivo dele é fazer com que  alert do Bootstrap desapareça depois de um breve período. Ele funciona normalmente quando o alert está diretamente no HTML, porém quando coloco o alert dentro do Jquery, ele não funciona. Vejam:

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm">
   <div class="modal fade" id="modalLogin">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header bg-dark text-white">
            <h4 class="modal-title font-weight-bold"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> ACESSO RESTRITO</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="erroLogin"></div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="login">Login:</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Coloque seu login">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
                     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Coloque sua senha">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group form-check text-right">
                     <label class="form-check-label"><small><a href="#!" style="color: blue">Esqueci a senha</a></small></label>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i> Acessar</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#loginForm').submit(function () {
                data = $('#loginForm').serialize();
                $.post("validar.php", {
                   d: data,
                },
                         function (d) {
                            console.log(d);
                            if (d == 0) {
                               $('#erroLogin').html("<div class='alert alert-danger text-left alertaLogin'><i class=\"fas fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i> Dados de acesso inválidos!</div>"); 
                            } 
                         });
                return false;
             });
       });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".alertaLogin").fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 3000 ).fadeOut( 400 );
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Fox, o código que mostra o alerta é executado quando a página é carregada, e no AJAX vc insere o alerta depois.

Comment: Perdoe-me Sam. Não consegui compreender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque no CSS a propriedade `display: none` na class `.alertaLogin`:

```
.alertaLogin{
   display: none;
}
```

Em seguida o código que mostra/esconde a div após o retorno do AJAX e após você inserir a div do alerta de erro:

```
if (d == 0) {
   $('#erroLogin').html("<div class='alert alert-danger text-left alertaLogin'><i class=\"fas fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i> Dados de acesso inválidos!</div>"); 
   $(".alertaLogin").fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 3000 ).fadeOut( 400 );
}
```

O `display: none` é necessário para que o `.fadeIn` surta efeito.

Comment: Perfeito Sam. Funcionou!!! Muito obrigado!